# GPU Usage in a non-GLSL OpenGL Application

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu

I read from the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#Fixed_function_and_modern_GPUs) that current Modern GPUs are only programmable using shaders.

> Modern GPUs no longer support fixed
>   function. Everything is done with
>   shaders. In order to preserve
>   compatibility, the GL driver generates
>   a shader that simulates the fixed
>   function. It is recommended that all
>   new modern programs use shaders. New
>   users need not learn fixed function
>   related operations of GL such as
>   glLight, glMaterial, glTexEnv and many
>   others.

Is that mean that if we are not implementing shader/GLSL in OpenGL, we actually don't access the GPU at all and only do the computation using the CPU?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. It means that all fixed function stuff is automatically converted to shaders by the drivers.

Comment: I see. So in this case, the converted apps will run on the GPU. However, does OpenGL-only app (no shaders) in older cards have the access to GPU? Or the application only run on the CPU?

Comment: The fixed-function pipeline in older versions of OpenGL is implemented on the GPU.

Answer (score 6):

> Everything is done with shaders. In
>   order to preserve compatibility, the
>   GL driver generates a shader that
>   simulates the fixed function.

These shaders still run on the GPU (as all shaders do). They are just automatically made for you.